# Unable to launch Andyroid virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

When I try to launch an Andyroid virtual machine I get the following message

> unable to launch vm process: Failed to load VMMR0.r0
>   (VERR_LDR_MISMATCH_NATIVE) (0x-8fffbffb)!

Here is a print screen

[image]

I also get this.

[image]

I'm on windows 10.  I had everything working perfectly earlier, and then it randomly stopped working.

Comment: The software you are using has explicit Windows 10 support?

Comment: I hate how everyone jumps to conclusions about windows 10 not being supported, when i stated that i had it working perfectly, and other people have had the exact same errors that I'm now getting but haven't been resolved.

Comment: I withdraw my comment.  If you cannot answer a simple question, then I cannot help you, on top of that you tagged the question with Virtualbox which isn't Andyroid which adds confusion to your question.

Comment: If `Andyroid` is a customized `VirtualBox`virtual machine, that should be stated, because that isn't clear from their website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try setting the compatibility mode of virtualbox to windows 8 as well as the andy. this works for me. I am running windows 10

Answer (score 1):

It works. I had the same problem and I just opened the Virtual Box app and I changed  the general settings: the "Type" And "Version" to Microsoft Windows and Windows 8.1 (64 bits) and then you just have to open again Andy's App and it will work

Answer (score 1):

I was able to change the properties for both the VM and Andy, Make it run in compatibility mode for win8. Then I also had to go in and delete this specific folder for them to both run smooth "Deleting the folder in c:\users\username\AppData\Local\VirtualStore"

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Same here on 2 machines. Worked without problems until the reboot.

EDIT: Deliting the folder in c:\users\username\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files worked for me ..

Regards,
Roger

Comment: You removed this folder from the host or the guest OS?  Which folder within this folder should be removed precisely, removing all the folders, removes application data most people want to keep.

Comment: I removed from the Host-OS .. this is not the programs-folder. That one here is located in APPDATA. Remove all in it. For me it looks like he saves some configuration data about not really compatible hardware.

Comment: I am aware of what the folder is and is used for.  I never said it was the `Programs Files`, what i said was, the folder contains application data when data isn't created in the %appdata% within the user's profile directory.  In other words i am saying is that you should be able to just remove the folder, that contains application data for just `Andyroid`, and achieve the same result.  I am asking for you to clarify you answer to indicate which folder that is.

Comment: At my PC, there was an folder called HP in it, at my Surface2Pro, there was a folder called oracle .. so I think that is not Andyroid specific

Comment: VirtualBox is an Oracle product.  The point of me asking these questions, is for you to clarify your answer, instead of just telling people to delete all their application data for every application they have installed which uses that location to store data in.